# How do I get thousands separators using number_format?

Tags: php

[number_format problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0hW8.png) <---- my image where number format 1.00 instead of 1,000,000

I am using this code to output a link:

```
label_cell(
    "<a target='_blank' " . ($amount<0 ? 'class="redfg"' : '')
    ."href='$path_to_root/sales/inquiry/customer_inquiry.php?amount=".$amount."'"
    ." onclick=\"javascript:openWindow(this.href,this.target); return false;\" >"
    . number_format($amount, 2, ',', '') // <-- how to display more than 1,000,000 instead of this would be display 1,00 ?
    ."</a>", $parms);
```

I want to display thousands seperators in the caption. For example:

- `1000000` should be `1,000,000.00`
- `100` should be `100.00`

However, I get:

- `1000000` as `1000000,00`
- `100` as `100,00`

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the logic behind the presentation here?  Why does `100,000` become `100.00`, with only two zeroes at the end?

Comment: i'm trying to display full value amount instead show 100.00 when reaching a million it would only display 1.00 instead 1,000,000 what is the problem with my number_format then

Comment: no want i mean is that 1.00 display i want full amount 1,000,000 to be display not 1.00

Comment: Please write an example of **input data**, the **current (wrong) result** and the **expected result**. Use the **edit** link below your question.

Comment: table amount ----> total
         1.00 <--- why is this  i want this show ----->           total amount would be 1,000,000

Comment: This is the output of your code: `<a target='_blank' href='/sales/inquiry/customer_inquiry.php?amount=1000035' onclick="javascript:openWindow(this.href,this.target); return false;" >1000035,00</a>
` looks ok, except there are no thousands separators but a decimal comma as implied by `number_format($amount, 2, ',', '')`.

Comment: how would i put  thousands separator in my code ?

Comment: See the answer below. If none of the answers fits your needs, you probably have some JavaScript running which reformats the page content.

Comment: Please check the recent edits again. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your problem is that you don't start with a number like `1000000`, you start with a **string** like `"1,000,000"`.

One option is to remove the commas before you pass $amount to number_format:

```
$amount = "1,000,035";
$amount = str_replace(',', '', $amount);
echo number_format ($amount, 2, '.', ',');
// output: 1,000,035.00
```

It would be better to go to the source of the data and try to remove the commas from there. You're going to find it inconvenient to remove these commas with these ad-hoc methods all over the place.

Comment: table still does not show full amount 1,000,000 instead show still 1.00 ?

Comment: Please update the question and add what you've tried, what was the original value of $amount you used, and what was the output

Comment: @KalmaKun In your browser select "view source" and add the generated link code to the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might want

```
number_format($amount, 2, '.', ',');
```

This converts `1000035` into the string `'1,000,035.00'`. The 3rd argument is the decimal separator, the 4th argument is the thousands separator.

If you do not want decimals at all, set the 2nd argument `0` and remove the dot.

```
number_format($amount, 2, '', ',');
```

The output would be `'1,000,035'`

Comment: but why does my table not show 1,000,035.00 this instead it shows 1.00 ? i'm at a lost